# VLC Hardware Decoding not working in Wayland but working fine in Xorg

Tags: xorg, vlc, wayland, 21.04, vaapi

I am trying to get hardware decoding for video in VLC in Wayland. `vainfo` in Xorg and Wayland is identical for me:
[image: vainfo in Wayland]
[image: vainfo in Xorg]

When I run VLC in Xorg, hardware decoding works fine:
[image: VLC in Xorg]
However in Wayland, it doesn't work:
[image: VLC in Wayland]

The test video has been downloaded from [here](https://test-videos.co.uk/bigbuckbunny/mp4-h264)

My laptop has Intel i5-4258U, so it supports hardware acceleration for h.264 videos. Can someone please help me understand why is this happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with VAAPI encoding in OBS. I installed the Intel nonfree driver which overrides the default one and it worked after that.  You can try :

```
sudo apt install intel-media-va-driver-non-free
```